# Using string as array index in Perl

Tags: perl

I have run into a strange behavior in Perl that I haven't been able to find documentation for. If I (by accident) use a string as an index in an array I get the first item of the array and not `undef` as I would have expected.

```
$index = "Some string";
@array = qw(one two three);
$item = $array[$index];
print "item: " . $item;
```

I expected to get `item:`  as output, but instead I get `item: one`. I assume that because the string doesn't start with a number it's "translated" to 0 and hence giving me the first item in the array. If the string starts with a number that part of the string seems to be used as the index.

Is this to be expected, and is there any documentation describing how strings (e.g. `"2strings"`) are interpreted as numbers in Perl?

Comment: Do you have `use strict; use warnings;` in your code? Please read following [webpage](https://squareperl.com/en/how-perl-convert-string-to-number) to get some information how __a strings__ converted to __integer__ (array index is an integer number).

Comment: @PolarBear The link is exactly what I was looking for. The real code I have problems with only have `use strict;`, but I have just tested with `warnings` in my test code, and got some nice warnings. Please upgrade to answer.

Comment: `use strict;` assumes that you declare variables properly `my $var = 'value';`, or `local $var = 'value';`, or `our $var = 'value';`. Take your time to read on [strict](https://perldoc.perl.org/strict) and [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings).

Comment: You can check free book [Modern Perl 4 edition](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf) to learn program in Perl with modern style.

Comment: @PolarBear If you create an answer from your comments, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Array index imposes numeric context. The string "Some string" in numeric context is equal to 0.

Under [warnings](https://perldoc.pl/warnings), Perl will complain

```
Argument "Some string" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Array indexes must be integers, so non-integer values are converted to integers.

The string `one` produces the number `0`, as well as the following warning:

```
Argument "Some string" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup
```

This concept is found throughout Perl. For the same reason, arguments to addition and multiplication will similarly be converted to numbers. And values used as hash keys will be converted to strings. Dereferencing undef scalars even produces the necessary value and reference in a process called autovivification!

```
$ perl -Mv5.10 -e'
   my $ref;
   say $ref // "[undef]";

   $ref->[1] = 123;
   say $ref // "[undef]";
'
[undef]
ARRAY(0x560b653ae4b8)
```

As you can see, an array and a reference to that array were spontaneously created in the above program because they were needed.

The lesson to take: *Always* use `use strict; use warnings;`.